# Python Recursion with counter

Tags: python, recursion

I have a recursive function like this:

```
b=4
def someFunction(x,y,z):
   global b
   b += x
   if...#something

   else:
       someFunction(x,y,z)
 ...
```

Theres a lot to it, but thats the general idea. My issue is that when running my program on cmd, I cant keep calling 'someFunction' with different parameters as there is no reset for b, however if I reset b within the function It won't work as I intend it to. So I could write this in two functions with the recursion in a sub function, but is there some other way to have b reset when I call the function without this being a problem when it starts recursion?

Comment: Set its value just before the first call to someFunction() is made?

Comment: 1. The recursion depth in python is limited, so try to avoid to use recursion if it's not really necessary
2. Instead of using the global variable you can pass it to the function, for examplу, the function definition: `def some_function(x, y, z, b=4)`
and recurrent calls should pass it inside: `some_function(new_x, new_y, new_z, b=b+x)`. It prevents the different possible race conditions connected, with the `b` simmultaionus access from differnet threads or async tasks

Comment: So, since `b` is global, you reset it outside of the function. And yes, the option is to wrap the recurstion into a function including the reset mechanism. But then `b` does not have to be global, but local to the reset-function. But ideally you just pass the new `b` to the function itself as a parameter. It's usually a bad idea to mix recursion and static variables (which you are emulating here).

Comment: The recursion limit by default is of the order of 1000. I have not ever got into any problems in real world cases but of course, ymmv depending what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is use an optional keyword argument, like this.

```py
def someFunction(x,y,z, b=None):
   if b is None:
       b = 4 
   b += x
   if...#something

   else:
       someFunction(x,y,z,b=b)
```

This way you can initialize the `b` on the first call to any value (and avoid usage of global variables).

This also has the positive that now `someFunction` is a ***pure function*** (no side effects and same input always gives same output) and much easier to work with. (Testing, refactoring, ..)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional parameter of the function with the reset value:

```
def someFunction(x,y,z, reset = None):

   if reset is not None:
      b=reset

   ...

   b += x
   if...#something

   else:
       someFunction(x,y,z)
```

then the first time just call `f(x,y,z, reset=4)`

Comment: This would still need the module level `b`. I would avoid the pattern if possible since pure functions are easier to work with.

Comment: fair enough - was just trying not to deviate too much from the case presented